# How do I only allow letters when asking for a name in python?

Tags: python, string, input

I am new to coding in python and need to know how to only allow the user to enter letters when inputting a name. So if they input a number or nothing at all, I want the code to say something like "Please only use letters, try again".

Cheers Chris

Answer (score 9):

What you are asking for is a `str.isalpha()` function:

```
isalpha(...)
   S.isalpha() -> bool

   Return True if all characters in S are alphabetic
   and there is at least one character in S, False otherwise.
```

For example you can use it like this:

```
def ask_name():
    while True:
        name = raw_input("What is your name?")
        if name.isalpha():
            return name
        else:
            print("Please use only letters, try again")
```